# How to get latest listbox item from another page - Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

If I have a listbox (called listBoxobj) on 'Page1' which is binding items from a local SQLite DB, how can I get the latest item ID from another page (Page2 for example). At the moment I have the following methods:

Page1:

```
private void listBoxobj_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxobj.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
            Refueling listitem = listBoxobj.SelectedItem as Refueling;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/EditRefuelingPage.xaml?SelectedContactID=" + listitem.Id, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Page2:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Selected_ContactId = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["SelectedContactID"]);
    currentrefuel = Db_Helper.ReadRefuel(Selected_ContactId);
}
```

This method is calling ReadRefuel() from the DataBaseHelper class

```
public Refueling ReadRefuel(int refuelid)
{
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {
        var existingrefuel = dbConn.Query<Refueling>("select * from Refueling where Id =" + refuelid).FirstOrDefault();
        return existingrefuel;
    }
}
```

I need another way to get the latest item ID (without clicking on it in the listbox). I tried to make one additional method in my CRUID class to get the latest ID with it:

```
        public Refueling GetLatestID()
    {
            using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
            {
            var latestID = dbConn.Query<Refueling>("select Id from Refueling").Last();
            return latestID;
            }
    }
```

Then do the following:

```
                int latestID = Convert.ToInt32(Db_Helper.GetLatestID());
                lastRefueling = Db_Helper.ReadRefuel(latestID);
                oldMileage = Convert.ToDouble(lastRefueling.Mileage);
```

,but got an exception: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

Actually with `int latestID = Convert.ToInt32(Db_Helper.GetLatestID());` i got an object of type Refueling, so i had to take the element Id from it like this:`lastRefueling = Db_Helper.ReadRefuel(latestID.Id);`